# Symfony 1.4 : How to generate .SQL from fixture files

Tags: sql, symfony1, fixtures

I have my symfony project on my dev box machine and also on a hosted environment where i have only FTP and HTTP access (i have a phpmyadmin access to my prod DB). This hosted version is an alpha release that should be initialized with fixtures.

Problem is : to do that, i have to write/update .yml fixtures in local, insert them in local DB with the symfony task, go on my local PMA, generate a data export, go on prod PMA and import the data...

Is there any way to generate a .sql file from my local fixtures so that i can insert them directly through my prod PMA ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably for you to look at this website:

http://brentertainment.com/2010/02/15/run-a-symfony-task-from-your-model-or-action/

You may run tasks from the web, you might make it a bit smarter and allow to run tasks from the web. Also clearing the cache might be a useful thing to extend to your admin interface for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't "out of the box" in symfony.

BUT you may be able to use the [Doctrine Profiler](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/component-overview%3aprofiler) to log all the SQL requests done by the sfDoctrineDataLoadTask task class into a file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `symfony doctrine:build --all` command? When I do that, a schema.sql file is created within the data/sql directory.

Comment: Correct. You should see two folders within data: fixtures and sql.